# Video Timeline with Pinch Zoom in Android

Tags: android, video, zooming, timeline, pinch

I've been searching for a Zoomable Video Timeline for android or something similar, but could only find one for iOS, it is a lot like what i need for Android [HERE IT IS](https://github.com/KenShih522/KSTimeline)

So my question is have any of you seen such a library or i shall create a custom view myself.

Comment: have you looked at ExoPlayer lib?

Comment: As far as I searched, I only found the standard timeline, and all the examples etc. were with the standard.

Comment: Okay, I think then you have to develop by yourself.